# Why would anyone use !! in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
// options
if (options) {
  this.deep = !!options.deep
  this.user = !!options.user
  this.lazy = !!options.lazy
  this.sync = !!options.sync
} else {
  this.deep = this.user = this.lazy = this.sync = false
}
```

While i was trying to understand vue.js Watcher i saw this syntax `!!options.deep` [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2ee516dfc8c72cf48ca7c77863216d93de0b30eb/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L47) i totally understand what `!` means, but why would anyone want to use `!!true` because it will give you `true` again.

Thanks

Comment: Yes `!!true` is `true`, but then so is `!!1` and `!!"hello world"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the variable is a boolean, then `!!` won't have any effect but if the variable is a number or another type, then it will be converted to a boolean.

```
!!false === false
!!true  === true
!!0     === false
!!1     === true
!!x     === Boolean(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

`!!` is an attempt to make coercion to Boolean in JavaScript. Same result will be with `Boolean(value)`